# copy multiple file selected by criteria in windows cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to copy from one directory to another, all files that have 2 digits format (ex. 12.txt, 15.pdf, 25.doc... etc), this is in Windows.

In Linux this works:

```
cp -t target_directory {10..99}.*
```

In Windows what will be the solution?

Comment: The question doesn't match the code, do you want files which have two digit names, or files which have names with two digits in the range `10` to `99`. One of the options seems to ignore these valid two digit names, `00`, `01`, `02`, `03`, `04`, `05`, `06`, `07`, `08` and `09`.

Comment: Files whitch have names with 2 digit formats (two digits in the range, like you say't).Hmmm, those files with names from 01--09 seems that will be ignored. Sugestion?

Comment: My suggestion is that you first determine what you need before taking up our time answering incomplete questions. Once you've done that, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50961630/edit) to provide all the information we need to provide a solution. That will include the code you have tried which is supposed to perform the tasks you've explained and which fails to do so, what happened when you ran it, and what you've tried to do yourself to fix it.

Comment: At the moment, the answer you've selected as correct doesn't match the question posed. Please either [adjust the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50961630/edit), so that the answer matches it, then ask a new properly formed question or unmark the solution, ask the real question and give Sergei Z, a reasonable opportunity to modify their answer before accepting someone else's.

Comment: Your edit is no less, _(**more**)_, ambiguous than the original!

Comment: This is better?

Comment: I rolled back your changes because changing the requirements is very bad as all answers provided so far become invalid. If you have other requirements, post a new question instead, but provide a [mcve] this time! Read also the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: @aschipfl, I note that the question was modified to extend the match criteria 28 minutes before your initial answer was posted, and their comment with the extended range of possible matches, _below the only posted answer at the time_, came 80 minutes before your answer was posted. For that reason **I do not believe that your rollback should stand**.

Comment: ok, I will try on diffrent post (to ask better)

Comment: @white_flag, please note before you do that, that StackOverflow is not a free code request service. Your question must include the code you have written, the full range of possible matches, examples of those files it failed to correctly match, what you've tried, _(to date)_, in correcting the issue and what happened when you did so. It may also be prudent, if posting a new question, to include with it a link to this question, such that responders can see a history of the issue.

Comment: @Compo, seems that I didn't refresh the page during answering; anyway, I did the rollback for the first answer to remain valid, although I'm still not sure whether or not it was really the best option; however, we could flag for moderator attention, what do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure of the best course of action, @aschipfl, because I'm not even sure if the OP knows what they want, or even if they do, whether they would have a valid on-topic question. I tried my best to guide them into editing their question to remove the ambiguity, and create something on-topic, before further responses came, such that the only person affected was the author of the existing answer. As it stands, I'd suggest it was deleted, or closed awaiting a clearly defined task and on-topic question. I have voted to close it!

Comment: @Compo, I see; I voted to close too...

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly but should work

`for /L %i in (10,1,99) do @copy %i.* dest_folder_here >nul 2>&1`

It tries every file in the range suppressing conditions. Adjust `copy` to overwrite if needed.

Comment: Double the percent symbols if you are using this in a batch-file.

Comment: one extra question: I try to play with the code line but I did not find my way. For example if some files have 12,1.txt 56,1.pdf. How will look the code to select also file name that have  ","

Comment: @white_flag, that is a completely different qusestion to that originally posted, because those are four character filenames containing two digits followed by a comma, followed by a digit, not two digit filenames in the range `10-99`. Sergei, this currently accepted solution looks to me that it would copy this filename, `99.Red.Balloons.Nena.mp3`, which I believe doesn't fit the critetia!

Answer (score 0):

I would filter for the correct files by [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), like this:

```cmd
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('dir /B /A:-D "??.*" ^| findstr /X "[0123456789][0123456789]\.[^.]*"') do copy "%%~I" "\path\to\destination"
```

I avoided to use range expressions `[0-9]` because they might also match `²`, `³`.

If you also want to match files with no file name extension, change the search string to `[0123456789][0123456789] [0123456789][0123456789]\.[^.]*`.

Comment: the code is working for all files with 11 ---- 99.*. For 11,1.txt or 01.xls not working!

Comment: Of course it is not working for such files, because your original question does not specify them. It should be quite obvious at least how to match files like `01.txt`. Thanks for changing the requirements after answers have been provided!